# How to fetch data from a nested array

Tags: php

May I know how to get the "product" value with foreach loop in PHP?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => "Sony"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => "Toshiba"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product] => "A4Tech"
        )

)
```

This is my code and I know it is not working after I tried it.

```
foreach($response as $key => $value){           

    foreach($key as $pic_small => $value2){

    echo $pic_small;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($response as $item)
   echo $item['product'];
```

ps: ok, foreach statement takes every first level element of $response array and set $item variable equal to it (you do not need indexes of the elements, so instead of the `$key => $value` only `$value` could be used). at the first loop it is the same as `$item = array('product' => 'Sony');`, at the second loop it is the same as `$item = array('product' => 'Toshiba');` and so on..

you may, of course, use the second foreach loop to deal with those arrays, but if you need the value of only one associative element with key `product` then you can access it directly through the value of `$item['product']`.

otherwise, as it is shown in another answer, you can done it as

```
// $item1 means element of the first level in the original array
// $key2 and $value2 are keys and values of the second level elements 
foreach($response as $item1)
     foreach($item1 as $key2 => $value2) // you may remove '$key2 =>' here
        echo $value2;
```

Comment: Care to write a sentence? It's rampant, but not actually good style to turn Stackoverflow into a code dump.

Comment: @mario  but the code is so obvious that it does not require any explanation.

Comment: It is very much so. But obviously not to OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($response as $key => $value){           

    foreach($value as $title => $value2){

        echo $value2;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the right answer. Except that it also lacks the explanation part.